# Using edge triggered epoll, should I loop over send?

Tags: epoll, epollet

I'm using epoll to write a media server. The fds are all set to non-blocking and I'm using edge-triggered events. I know for EPOLLIN I need to loop over reading the fd until EAGAIN is returned. But what about writing?

When I want to write I queue the data and set EPOLLOUT|EPOLLIN|EPOLLET on the fd. When the EPOLLOUT event occurs I write the whole queued buffer in one shot:

```
n = send ( fd, buf, buf_len, MSG_NOSIGNAL );
```

If n > 0 && n < buf_len I just reset EPOLLOUT and return. I don't see the sense in looping over send (which I think the man page for epoll implies). It seems like send has indicated it has just taken in all it can and will return EAGAIN if called immediately.

Is eliminating a system call here the most efficient route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

epoll man page says:

For  stream-oriented  files  (e.g., pipe, FIFO, stream socket), the condition that the read/write I/O space is exhausted can also be detected by checking the amount of  data read  from  / written to the target file descriptor.  **For example, if you call read(2) by asking to read a certain amount of data and  read(2)  returns  a  lower  number  of bytes, you can be sure of having exhausted the read I/O space for the file descriptor. The same is true when writing using write(2).**  (Avoid this  latter  technique  if  you cannot guarantee that the monitored file descriptor always refers to a stream-oriented file.)

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bunch of tests and it seems like looping over send is a waste of time.